# Build SQLite database from JSON file in runtime - is it Good?

Tags: android, json, optimization

I need opinion regarding rendering of data in android app. I have all the data stored in a json file `abc.json` which is in `res > raw` folder. i have a class that then reads data from that json file and build SQLite database when the app runs and later on i'm performing all operations like searching the data using sql queries for that database. But i am afraid if thats not a good option and the code is not optimized because code now contains so many functions for adding the items to database.

For example, json file has Authors, books, keywords, references, acknowledgements, subauthors and when the database is built, data is read and a specific function is called for each item. I'm just concerned because of too many functions as one for each item. Like whenever json is parsed for an item, e.g author, it calls `addAuthors` function to add that to database. Following are 2 of the functions for example.

```
//Sample function code for adding authors to db
public void addAuthors(Integer id, String Name, String is_corresponding) {

    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

    value.put("_id", id);

    value.put("NAME", Name);

    value.put("IS__CORRESPONDING", is_corresponding);

    authors_id = database.insert(TABLENAME_AUTHOR, null, value);
}

//example function for adding keywords to db
public void addKeyWord(String KeyWords, Integer id) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("KEYWORDS", KeyWords);

    values.put("_id ", id);

    database.insert(TABLENAME_ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS, null, values);

}
```

**I need help with optimizing my code. Is there any way to optimize the current code ?** Kindly help me with this and suggest some improvements for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you parse your json more than once?

Comment: @323go. No I'm parsing once.. I have updated my question with getData() function of my app which i use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend bundling a sqlite database as an asset in your APK instead of bundling the JSON file and then inserting the data into a database. If your data isn't changing, you can then get rid of all your insert functions. You will also save the cost of creating and populating your database dynamically.

You can use the methods described [here](http://www.xatik.com/2012/03/19/android-preloaded-database/) to create your database and to copy it from the assets of your APK. Be sure to copy it first before you try to open in in your app -- you can't open it directly as an asset.